# How do I use Rails as purely a JSON application server with a Backbone UI?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, json, user-interface, backbone.js

I'm starting a new web app.  I've decided that with using Twitter Bootstrap I can actually make this app look pretty good!  So this has inspired me to really focus on the user experience of the app.  Really polish it and make it shine.

So, naturally, there is going to be a lot of front-end JS work.  Being a Rails 3 fan, I thought about using Rails (along with its generators, easy ActiveRecord, etc) as just a backend platform for working with JSON.  So Backbone would perform CRUD operations and Rails would handle the server-side stuff.

In fact, I don't even want to use Rails' template system.  I thought about just using pure HTML and serve them statically with nginx.

Backbone and jQuery would be responsible for updating sections of the pages.

Is my logic sane?  The main reason I want to do this is that I want a pure, front-end, experience that the user will enjoy.  Plus, the nature of my app really lends well to no page refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that would work fine. You can do basically that same thing with just about any language and server on the backend these days including Node.js, Rails, Java with something like Jersey (that's what we use), PHP, etc.

The Backbone front end just treats the back end as a query and persistence service that it accesses via URLs. Serve up JSON data from those URLs and Backbone will be happy as a clam.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  And that is even the way we are moving here at my real job.  Basically using ExtJS to talk to Struts via JSON.  I even thought about using Sinatra since I love Ruby and the routes in Sinatra are easy.  But Rails provides a lot of nifty generators.  What are your thoughts on that?  Do you think rails is too bloated for that?  Thanks.

Comment: It is a long time since I used Rails but I loved it when I used it, I can't say I ever thought of it as bloated and wouldn't even if I was just using it for a REST service like this situation. That's just my purely subjective assessment though. Some people would look at it and say, "Why not use a compiled language like Java because you could scale it to umptee-ump users, or use a Node.js server because then you're using JavaScript on both the server side and the client side, or use _fill in the blank_ because its the new hotness."

Comment: Yeah, I found that I wasted a whole weekend with Nodejs because I wanted JS on both sides.  Really missed migrations and ActiveRecord.